# Copy only files, not folder structure from a directory in Unix

Tags: unix, cp

I found this solution after googling [here](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=24778) but I was horrified: too complicated solution. I am pretty sure some cp -versions have flags for this or just simple `find` will do. So how do you copy files, not directory structure, in Unix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `find`, cannot find a flag in my GNU Coreutils 8.5 `cp` about not-preserving directory-structure. Anyway the one-liner:

```
find . -type f -exec cp '{}' ~/Backup/ \;
```

Answer (score 6):

`find path-to-source-file-tree -type f -exec cp {} path-to-target-dir \;`

That should take care of all your issues.

To customize it further you can refer: `man find` For example, based on date and time, file types, file owners, etc. you can customize the above statement.

Comment: ...err the same as mine?

Comment: @hhh: Well you asked the question and you answered it before I could finish my answer. :)

Comment: Odd, I answered it and asked at the same time. I tried to archieve this to SO and get previewed because interested whether any other way :) But yeah that way probably is the best way, not aware of any better.

Comment: @hhh: Why did you want to archive a question?

Comment: Because google was poor/misleading and I am interested whether other ways exist, there may be some command to do this with just a flag. By asking very simple question like this, you improve G results and get your ideas previewed.

Comment: No because it is an answer to my question :)

Comment: Can anyone explain the `\;` at the end? And how it differs from having a `+` at the end, which is the other version of the command? Yes I read the manual but I was hoping someone could explain it in Captain Dummy talk.